# Is there anyway to get the date showing on ChromeOS

Tags: google-chrome-os

I am running ChromeOS on a Samsung Chromebook and was wondering if there is any way to get the date to appear alongside the time on the bottom right hand corner of the screen.

There doesn't appear to be any setting to do this so I imagine if it is possible it will be a flag set somewhere? Again looking about didn't come up with anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.